# javascript - validate nested property dynamically

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Let's say I have the following `JavaScript` object.

```
let obj = {
  "type": "user",
  "personalDetails": {
    "firstName": "Steven",
    "address": {
      "streetName": "abcd",
      "zipCode": "012345"
    }
  },
  "employeeDetails": {
    "designation": {
      "id": "1234",
      "manager": "Mark",
    }
  }
}
```

How can I validate the keys for this object in a cyclic manner dynamically. Meaning,

```
validateObject(obj, [1Level, 2Level....]) // examples below

validateObject(obj, [personalDetails])   // should return true since obj has personalDetails
validateObject(obj, [personalDetails, firstName])   // should return true since obj has personalDetails which has firstName
validateObject(obj, [personalDetails, address, streetName ])   // should return true since obj has personalDetails which has address which has streetName
validateObject(obj, [personalDetails, address, streetName, anyObj ])   // should return false since obj has personalDetails which has address which has streetName but streetName does not have anyObj
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let obj = {
  "type": "user",
  "personalDetails": {
    "firstName": "Steven",
    "address": {
      "streetName": "abcd",
      "zipCode": "012345"
    }
  },
  "employeeDetails": {
    "designation": {
      "id": "1234",
      "manager": "Mark",
    }
  }
}

console.log(validateObject(obj, ["personalDetails"]))   // should return true since obj has personalDetails
console.log(validateObject(obj, ["personalDetails", "firstName"]))   // should return true since obj has personalDetails which has firstName
console.log(validateObject(obj, ["personalDetails", "address", "streetName" ]))   // should return true since obj has personalDetails which has address which has streetName
console.log(validateObject(obj, ["personalDetails", "address", "streetName", "anyObj" ]))   // should return false sin

function validateObject(obj, arr) {
  let objectTovalidate = obj;
  for (let a of arr ) {
    if(!objectTovalidate.hasOwnProperty(a)) {
        return false;
    }
    objectTovalidate = objectTovalidate[a];
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive function, like so (or something similar):

```js
function validateObject(object, keys) {
  const [key] = keys;
  if (typeof key === "undefined") {
    return true;
  }
  if (!Object.keys(object).includes(key)) {
    return false;
  }
  return validateObject(object[key], keys.slice(1));
}

let obj = {
  "type": "user",
  "personalDetails": {
    "firstName": "Steven",
    "address": {
      "streetName": "abcd",
      "zipCode": "012345"
    }
  },
  "employeeDetails": {
    "designation": {
      "id": "1234",
      "manager": "Mark",
    }
  }
}

console.log(validateObject(obj, ["personalDetails"]));
console.log(validateObject(obj, ["personalDetails", "firstName"]));
console.log(validateObject(obj, ["personalDetails", "address", "streetName"]));
console.log(validateObject(obj, ["personalDetails", "address", "streetName", "anyObj"]));
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a recursive helper function. I simply just search the every embedded object to see if the key exists.

```
const validateObject = (obj, fieldsArr) => {
  for(let i = 0; i <fieldsArr.length; i++){
    const field = fieldsArr[i];
    const fieldExists = findFieldInObject(obj, field);
    if(!fieldExists){
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}

const findFieldInObject = (obj, field) => {
  const objKeys = Object.keys(obj);

  for(let i = 0; i < objKeys.length; i++){
    const key = objKeys[i];
    if(field === key){
      return true;
    }

    if(typeof obj[key] === 'object'){
      // Check this embedded object
      return findFieldInObject(obj[key], field);
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```